# How to open an hdf5 not in library root

Tags: python, h5py

I can't open hdf5 files using `h5py.File()` function unless the files are in the root folder, and I was wondering if there's anyway to change this.

I've already been able to open up the files in the root folder this same way but as soon as a file goes inside of another folder within the root, it throws an error. I've also tried opening it with the path and it didn't work.

```
# string together file name for field data
file = 'magnets-l2_current-' + date_time

# import file
m = h5py.File(file, 'r')
```

> OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'magnets-l2_current-20190506-102013.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

This is the error it throws. Again, I have my venv folder as the root, and I can open any data files that are in that folder. But any files inside `venv/Data/...` I cannot open.

Comment: have you tried putting in the entire path? '/whatever/venc/Data/magnets-l2_current-20190506-102013.hdf5'

Comment: Adding full path to folder is one solution (and the most robust).  If you are running in an IDE, some give the option to control the working directory. For example: Spyder has 3 options: 1) directory of file being executed, 2) current working directory, 3) user defined directory. FWIW, I always test my input file names before using them to confirm they exist and have write permission (if I need it).